# Deleting the system keychain from Mac, specified keychain could not be found

Tags: macos, passwords, keychain

I want to delete Keychain stored in `System.keychain` folder on Mac. I tried the following,

```
security delete-keychain Keychain_name
```

but got the following error:

> The specified keychain could not be found

How can I remove the keychain?  When it didn't work I tried giving the path where the keychain is stored

```
security delete-keychain Keychain_name /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
```

But even then I am getting the same error message.

I want to delete it as I'm developing applications, some of the information is stored as such. If i try to delete a single item it gives the above error.

However, When I used the following command

```
sudo security delete-keychain /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
```

it deleted the entire System.keychain.

Where am I going wrong in deleting single item from system.keychain?

Comment: Try it just by specifying system.keychsin, not the full path. And your question asks about deleting the entire keychain, not a single item, therefore the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's go over the terminology:

`System.keychain` and `login.keychain` are *keychains*. These *contain* keychain items like *password items* and *secure note items*.

---

`security delete-keychain` deletes an *entire keychain*. That's what my first comment was about: You usually *do not want to delete the System keychain, including all its entries*. You use this if you create your own keychains for specific uses.

```
security delete-keychain "/Users/danielbeck/Library/Keychains/Test.keychain"
```

---

Use `security delete-generic-password`, `security delete-internet-password`, or `security delete-certificate`, depending on the kind of item you want to delete, instead.

The following command deletes an item, e.g. a *Secure Note*, named `note` from the specified keychain `Test2.keychain`:

```
security delete-generic-password -l note "/Users/danielbeck/Library/Keychains/Test2.keychain"
```

For information about the options that allow you to specify which items to delete, see `man security`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply it was very helpful...but i got another problem when i use the delete command in terminal it succeeds but when i try to delete it using script it is not getting deleted

Comment: @chitnisprasanna I suggest you create a new question about that, providing *much more* information. What kind of script, the exact command you're executing, how others can replicate the issue you're experiencing, etc.